# Show ubercart attribute only if other attribute is checked

Tags: javascript, drupal, attributes, conditional-statements, ubercart

If you have a set of attributes that should only be available to a product (shown to the user and then selectable), if a certain other attribute is checked, how would one accomplish this?

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your question is a module called CANTO. Search for it on ubercart.org. Here is the module in action, also to have attributes with descriptions and images use the Dynamic Product Pages module found on drupal. https://www.illusiongrouppcs.com/node/32
If you select the last case (a full tower) the next attribute will POP up only showing motherboards that support full tower cases.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not perhaps looking for [uc_conditional_attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_conditional_attributes)? Only problem is there is no Drupal 8 version of it.